# Missing body in JMS / websocket message

Tags: java, spring, websocket, jms, stomp

I'm trying to understand why serialized objects are being stripped out when received.

Here is the general layout :
1. Produce JMS messages and send to a topic on an external ActiveMQ broker. The code is based off the Spring boot JMS message and can be viewed at http://bit.ly/QECQ21  . In my example, I generate various types of messages (text , POJO, Map)
2. I have 2 JMS consumers that subscribe to this topic.

a. One is a java client. This client correctly identifies all the various message types.

b. The 2nd client is a javascript client based on websockets + stomp.js . This correctly identifies text messages but not messages that contain POJOs generated by my producer.

Here is the sample output from the web client (source at http://bit.ly/Od0noF ) .

What am I doing wrong? Something wrong with the the addressing or something else in the code? Something about the way I'm using (or misusing) STOMP? I had to use "tcp://localhost:61616" in the Application.java class to correctly contact the broker.

Thanks

MESSAGE priority:4 persistent:true subscription:sub-0 expires:0 timestamp:1396418227090 destination:/topic/greetings message-id:ID:blackbox-53461-1396418226684-1:1:2:1:1 content-length:4 ping

Body:ping

---

MESSAGE priority:4 persistent:true subscription:sub-0 expires:0 timestamp:1396418227117 destination:/topic/greetings message-id:ID:blackbox-53461-1396418226684-1:1:2:1:2

Body: ======> missing body

---

MESSAGE priority:4 persistent:true subscription:sub-0 expires:0 timestamp:1396418227122 destination:/topic/greetings message-id:ID:blackbox-53461-1396418226684-1:1:2:1:3

Body: ======> missing body

---

MESSAGE priority:4 persistent:true subscription:sub-0 expires:0 timestamp:1396418227125 destination:/topic/greetings message-id:ID:blackbox-53461-1396418226684-1:1:2:1:4 content-length:5 close

Body:close

---

Answer (score 1):

No answers yet so I'll add my findings. STOMP is a text based protocol and as such the body needs to be converted to a text format (such as JSON). In my case,  this can be done using the spring websockets framework (which internally uses Jackson) or by explicitly coding the  object into JSON using Jackson and them transmitting as a text message